# How do I get the start date for the current week in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

using: SQL Server 2008r2
via: aspx HTML page

I need to find the start date for the current week. It does not matter if it gives me Sunday's date or Monday's date, but I need to be able to find all transactions this week, for example.

Also, if someone can point me to a page that explains all the Date functions in SQL2008 that would be splendid too!

I searched around and found not much that was applicable (either I didn't search with the right keywords or there literally is no-one who has asked this before!)

Comment: The _SQL Server Books Online_ that comes with the product has explanations of the date functions, as well as all other functions available.

Comment: You can use the *set date_first* command to control which weekday is regarded as the *first* of the week: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of `dateadd` and `datediff` will accomplish this.

```
select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Note that `wk` is the abbreviation for the `week` datepart parameter in `dateadd`.

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.105).aspx) clearly and comprehensively explains the Date (and Time) methods in SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: can you help me find the number of days so far this week? (currently it will say 1, but tomorrow i want 2)    I'll post it as a new question, because there are some other twists too.

Comment: Sure, post the new question and I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: I want to count the number of active dates within a table, so that if one day had no records, it would be omitted from the count

Comment: Oh dear. It falls over now that we're in a new month. it returns 1, not 3. @killQuotes, any ideas?

Comment: 3 would be the end of the current week. You want it to return 3?

Comment: Whoops. My bad - I am on the wrong question. This one works perfectly. Sorry!